# Origin Policy violation on google.by pages

Tags: google-search, security-policy

Starting from today I'm constantly getting this error when trying to search something at google.by:

> Well, well, well. What do we have here? An Origin Policy violation.
>
> And what do we not have? A page!
>
> You're trying to go to:
>   https://www.google.by/search?q=thymeleaf+is+0+or+zero&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
>   The policy applies to: https://www.google.by

I tried other domains (google.com, google.ru, google.de) and they are working fine. The issue is reproducible in incognito mode (with plugins disabled). In Chrome only (Firefox and Edge have no such problem) and it started recently, so it may be related to the recent Chrome update. Now I use Chrome Version 71 (Beta).

1. What does it mean?
2. I didn't change something in my connection settings. Who is in charge? Google? ISP?

**UPD.** I'm not the only one with this problem, there're other user reports of this issue on [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/chrome/origin$20policy$20violation).

Comment: Does this happen if you do it immediately at the start a new Chrome session? Just close all windows of Chrome, start it again and issue the query.

Comment: @harrymc No, the problem is gone after restart. I still don't know the cause of it. Chrome update and [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/changelog.php?version=4.7.44) plugin update are the main suspects.

Comment: Can confirm, same happened on google.ca yesterday. Was gone after chrome restart, just happened again right now but now it's persisting across restarts.

Comment: Perhaps this [Chromium patch](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7e618744354e3faee1b8ee8d4b75537784a668c7) was to blame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for such a problem that the answer returned by `google.by`
tried to access data which was stored by a previous website request.

[Wikipedia Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)
explains well the problem:

> The following example illustrates a potential security risk that could arise without the same-origin policy. Assume that a user is visiting a banking website and doesn't log out. Then, the user goes to another site that has some malicious JavaScript code running in the background that requests data from the banking site. Because the user is still logged in on the banking site, the malicious code could do anything the user could do on the banking site. For example, it could get a list of the user's last transactions, create a new transaction, etc. This is because the browser can send and receive session cookies to the banking site based on the domain of the banking site.

I have no real idea why issuing a query on `google.by` would cause a
reference that would trigger a same-origin policy block, but it is clear
that this has prevented an inappropriate access to your data.

Google is one of the most-used avenues for malware, so it's possible that its
ads system brought you a shady reference.

If this happens again, do the same thing: Restart Chrome.
The chances are that the same ad won't be served again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the Dev channel of Chrome and have the flag `Experimental Web Platform features` enabled [1], then it could be the cause according to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Idlk6fx28v4).

If the flag is enabled, try disabling it and restart Chrome.

---

[1] Check the flag here: `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`

Comment: The problem does not bother me after Chrome restart. The flag `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` is still on. I've read through the linked topic and it does not contain any explanation on why this flag was the cause.